# java issue creating float[]

Tags: java

I am trying to create a `float[]` depending on the user selection. In the code below, the variable `widths` is not recognized outside the `if` block. How can I dynamically create a `float[]` or append a `float[]`?

```
if(!dangerCheckBox.isSelected()){
    float[] widths = {100, 250, 70};
} else {
    float[] widths = {100, 250, 70, 70};
}
```

Comment: This is a really basic "beginning java" sort of thing, may I suggest any array tutorial? For example: [this one](http://www.janeg.ca/scjp/lang/arrays.html).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just put it outside.

```
    float[] widths;        

    if(!dangerCheckBox.isSelected()){
        widths = new float[] {100, 250, 70};
    } else {
        widths = new float[] {100, 250, 70, 70};
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Put the declaration outside the block: `float[] widths;` and then assign to `widths` inside the blocks.

Answer (score 1):

First you create that array using `new`  . After that assign your floating point numbers.

And other thing your float array declare in inside that `if` block. Declare this float array on outside that block.

```
float[] widths = null;

 if(!dangerCheckBox.isSelected()){
         widths = new float[]{100, 250, 70};
    } else {
         widths = new float[]{100, 250, 70, 70};
    }
```

Comment: It's not necessary to initialize `widths` to `null` in the first line, since you're going to always assign another value anyway.

Comment: yes, float[] widths = null; and float[] widths these two widths array are null. I used `null` for code clarity.

Comment: @Kushan: that's just not true, accessing an uninitialized array is a compilation error.  Of course in this case that may be the desired behavior.